# ¿Por qué no puedo salir del ciclo "while" con "break"?

Tags: python, bucles, while

Al momento de responder la pregunta inicial con "no" para que no entre al ciclo, aun así entra a él y si ingreso "si" el ciclo es infinito y no pregunta por el dato 6.

Este es el código:

```
dato = "si"
input("Pregunta inicial para entrar al ciclo (si/no): ")
while dato == "si":
    dato1 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato1: ")
    dato2 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato2: ")
    dato3 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato3: ")
    dato4 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato4: ")
    dato5 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato5: ")
    if dato != "si":
        break
dato6 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato6: ")
```

Comment: El `input` inicial no está guardando lo que el usuario responda. ¿No debería ser `dato = input("Pregunta inicial...")`? Con eso solucionarías lo de que no entre al bucle si responde "no". Pero si responde "si", de todas formas tu bucle sería infinito, ya que el valor de `dato` no vuelve a cambiar nunca dentro del bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dato = "si" # le asignas a dato el valor "si"
input("Pregunta inicial para entrar al ciclo (si/no): ") 
#haces una pregunta al usuario y no la guardas en ningun sitio
```

Para guardar lo que el usuario ingrese debes hacerlo asi:

```
dato = input("Pregunta inicial para entrar al ciclo (si/no): ")
```

Ahora el bucle:

```
while dato == "si": # este valor permanece inmutable 
# ya que no cambias el valor de dato, el bucle se ejecutara de forma infinita
    dato1 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato1: ")
    dato2 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato2: ")
    dato3 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato3: ")
    dato4 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato4: ")
    dato5 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato5: ")
    if dato != "si": # dato no ha cambiado y la comprobación es redundante
        break
dato6 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato6: ")
```

Imagino que lo que quieres es esto:

```
dato = "si"
dato = input("Pregunta inicial para entrar al ciclo (si/no): ")
while dato == "si":
    dato = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato: ")
```

Si no es así, especifica que es lo que buscas

Comment: Muchas gracias, el segundo código fue lo que necesitaba, efectivamente solo necesitaba que la pregunta para entrar al ciclo estuviera como una variable "dato = input("Pregunta inicial para entrar al ciclo (si/no): ")"

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que se entre en un bucle y solo se salga cuando el valor cambie, ese valor debe cambiar *dentro* del bucle. Y eso no está pasando actualmente.

Por tanto, tu algoritmo debería ser algo así como:

```
dato = "si"
while dato == "si":
    # ...
    dato = input("Pregunta inicial para entrar al ciclo (si/no): ")

dato6 = input("Ingrese el nombre del dato6: ")
```

Fíjate que no hay necesidad alguna de `break`, pues la condición se va revisando en cada iteración.

Si quisieras usar `break` igualmente podrías decir:

```
while True:  # esto pasa siempre
   # haz cosas
   if pasa_algo:
      break
```